# T-SQL: % difference between two dates within three days

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to work out the percentage difference between two dates, here is an example that currently works perfectly:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_ACCEPTED) * 100.00 
        FROM Child_Social.FACT_MISSING_PERSON AS mp
        WHERE mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_ACCEPTED LIKE 'Y'
        AND CAST (mp.END_DTTM AS DATE) 
        BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE))
        /
        (SELECT COUNT(mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_OFFERED)
        FROM Child_Social.FACT_MISSING_PERSON AS mp
        WHERE mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_OFFERED LIKE 'Y'
        AND CAST (mp.END_DTTM AS DATE) 
        BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE))
--Subquery to determine % between # of interviews offered vs # of interviews accepted
    FROM Child_Social.FACT_MISSING_PERSON AS mp
    WHERE CAST (mp.END_DTTM AS DATE) 
        BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Above I'm taking all interviews that were  accepted in a year, and dividing that by the number of interviews that were offered within that year. This generates 58% for me, using the numbers behind the query:

```
SELECT 426 * 100.00 / 725
```

However, using the same principle on a slightly different query I'm not getting the expected figures. I'm looking to see this, which generates 50.90%:

```
SELECT 253 * 100.00 / 497
```

But I keep getting "1"? The big difference in the query below is that I'm trying to determine the percentage for how many interviews were conducted within three days of the end date (END_DTTM), hence the <=3 clause, which I imagine is causing the issue

```
SELECT COUNT(mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_DATE) * 100  /
    (SELECT COUNT(mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_DATE) 
        FROM Child_Social.FACT_MISSING_PERSON AS mp
        WHERE CAST (mp.END_DTTM AS DATE) 
        BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE) AND
        (DATEDIFF(DAY, mp.END_DTTM, mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_DATE)) <=3) 
    FROM Child_Social.FACT_MISSING_PERSON AS mp
    WHERE CAST (mp.END_DTTM AS DATE) 
        BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

I'm a bit stumped all told, I've tried a few different things but I can't get it work, any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your second query, you're doing all integer math because you multiply by `100` rather than `100.00` as in the first query.

What answer do you get if you multiply by `100.00` in the second query?

Also, do you get the expected numbers if you select the numerator and denominator separately?

```sql
SELECT COUNT(mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_DATE), /* * 100 */
    (SELECT COUNT(mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_DATE) 
        FROM Child_Social.FACT_MISSING_PERSON AS mp
        WHERE CAST (mp.END_DTTM AS DATE) 
        BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE) AND
        (DATEDIFF(DAY, mp.END_DTTM, mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_DATE)) <=3) 
    FROM Child_Social.FACT_MISSING_PERSON AS mp
    WHERE CAST (mp.END_DTTM AS DATE) 
        BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for responding, I managed to solve the problem by doing my <=3 at the beginning of the query rather than at the end

Answer (score 0):

This is what provided me with the solution I wanted. Essentially it was about creating the WHERE clause earlier in the statement to derive the number of interviews within three days. In my original query I was trying to <=3 at the end of the query rather than at the beginning, hence why it kept generating the wrong number for me

In short this query generates this: `SELECT 724 / 253` = 34%

```
,(SELECT COUNT(mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_ACCEPTED) * 100 AS IntWithin3Days
    FROM Child_Social.FACT_MISSING_PERSON AS mp
    WHERE (DATEDIFF(DAY, mp.END_DTTM, mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_DATE)) <=3
    AND CAST (mp.END_DTTM AS DATE) 
    BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE))
    /
(SELECT COUNT(mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_OFFERED) AS TotalInt
    FROM Child_Social.FACT_MISSING_PERSON AS mp
    WHERE mp.RETURN_INTERVIEW_OFFERED LIKE 'Y'
    AND CAST (mp.END_DTTM AS DATE) 
    BETWEEN DATEADD(YY, -1, CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND CAST (GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS [Percentage of Interviews Within 3 Days]
```

--Subquery to determine % of interviews within 3 days